# How to find image on screen if there are rapid objects moving over it?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, pyautogui, image-recognition

I am currently discovering image recognition and my goal is to get all the informations from the board of a mobile game that look like this :
[board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8el0y.jpg)

As you can see, there are 5 different dices, their level can be between 1 and 7.

I know that AI recognition could solve this but I think it may be too much.
Another idea i have is to make an average of lets say 20 frames so the projectiles will be erased (not really sure)

For example, projectiles can look like this :
[dice with projectiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oFKr.png)

I want to get all the information from the board.
It would be a 5*3 array with dice type and level for every position

I tried using pyautogui to look on the screen for each possible appearance of a dice but I encountered two problems:

- Detection time: with 1-2 images it was quite fast but once I added 14 (so two dice with every level), It became way too slow.
- Projectiles: Dices are firing projectiles that go over them, theses are not really annoying on early dice levels as their attack speed is slow and I correctly detect dices types and levels, but on higher level, they fire a lot faster and detection start to struggle.

I did all my test on the top-left position of the board with this:

```py
def computeBoard():
  saw = False
  for dice in dicesList:
    try:
      if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(dice, region=(940, 580, 65, 65), confidence=0.90) is not None:
        print("I can see " + dice)
        saw = True
        break
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
      pass
  if saw == False:
    print("I can't see any dice")
```

Lowering the tolerance helps the detection, but the program confounds different levels together.

(dicesList is simply a list of all images path)

Also I selected python because it's used on the tutorial I saw on youtube, but I can switch without problems if needed.

Are there solutions to my problem ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another idea i have is to make an average of lets say 20 frames so the projectiles will be erased ...
>
> Are there solutions to my problem?

Yes, absolutely, you can easily "erase" the moving objects.

But rather than Average, prefer
[Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_data_set_of_numbers).
Averaging will leave behind faint ghost traces of projectiles.
Median OTOH is a robust statistic that will completely
discard such outliers.

Suppose that if we're given N frames,
a projectile will reliably enter then exit a given point.
Then computing each point's median brightness value
across slightly more than 2 × N frames will
reliably remove any projectile artifacts.
(Now, if *another* projectile follows very
closely upon its heels, you will need additional input frames.)

Comment: Thank you really much !

the median is working pretty well, it completly removes the projectiles and i'm able to get the board information.

Comment: Excellent! BTW, notice that you don't need _every_ sequential frame. Suppose it takes five frames for a projectile to move further than its own diameter. If you discard 80% of frames, sampling every fifth frame, then computing median over a mere three frames might suffice.

Comment: Oh I see, i'll take a look at this too. I'm not sure it would change much because the dices are firing projectiles really often, so I need to take a quite big amount of frames. But it could maybe resolve my speed problem :) Thanks